# dynamically changing content of the span element in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In my application ,i have a order page which contains products which we can order.If i order a product the CartTotal becomes changed(nothing but the amount is assigned to the span element).If i am not ordering any products the CartTotal will be nothing(span content is nothing) as follows,

Cart Total:

but when i open the order page Cart total will be nothing as shown above.But i need it as " 
"Cart is Empty" as follow.

Cart Total: Cart is Empty
So my requirement is untill i order atleast one product the cart total is showing that the cart is empty.

So how to do it.my cart total view coding is as follows,

**Cart Total:** 
 
here if i order the product the amount is assigned to span element as

$('#cart-total').text('$' + data.CartTotal.toFixed(2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="total">
    <strong>Cart is empty</span>
</div>
```

and then when someone adds a product:

```
$('#total strong').text('Cart Total: $' + data.CartTotal.toFixed(2));
```